# Generar autoincrement en c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un formulario en ASP.NET donde quiero aumentar en 1 el Id en un textbox y se muestre en la caja de texto, cada que el usuario realice una alta en un boton se tiene que actualizar.

Realice este codigo pero no me funciona, no muestra el Folio en la caja de texto

```
  private void Id()
    {
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn = new SqlConnection(this.conexion);
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select max(Folio) from Datos;";
            int valor = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()) + 1;
            txtfolio.Text = Convert.ToString(valor);
        }
        catch(System.Exception ex)
        {

        }
 }
```

El metodo lo agregué en el botón Alta:

```
      protected void Alta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Id();
  }
```

Comment: Hola, sólo comentarte que un catch() vacío es una muy mala práctica. Puede provocar, como así ha sido, que se obvie alguna excepción que deba ser controlada. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si no tienes ninguna fila te va a devolver null, tu programa falla en la linea donde conviertes "null" a int, esa conversión no se puede hacer, te recomiendo que cambies tu consulta por algo asi:

```
select case when max(Folio) is null then 0 else max(Folio) end from Datos
```

Así, desde la consulta te va a devolver 0 cuando no tengas registros y evitas el problema del null

**Edit:**

No me percaté de que no habias asignado la conexión al SqlCommand, agrega esto:

```
cmd.Connection = conn;
```

Justo antes de llamar a ExecuteScalar.

Comment: El Folio no lo muestra

Comment: Quita el try catch para que falle tu programa, pon la falla en un comentario para determinar por qué no funciona

Comment: "la propiedad Connection no se ha inicializado. " esto es lo que dice

Comment: Entonces el problema no es la generación del folio, es que no estás haciendo bien la conexión a la base de datos, ¿Ya verificaste que tu servidor de base de datos esté funcionando bien y tu cadena de conexión esté correcta? ¿Qué tienes en this.conexion?

Comment: La conexión está tal y cómo hago el update de mis registros y si lo hace. Esto es como lo tengo en mi demas codigo:                                           string conexion = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Sistema;User ID=sa;Password=*****";                                                                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

Comment: En tu código, después de cmd.CommandText = ... pon cmd.Connection = conn; no vi que no habías asignado la conexión al SqlCommand

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con un isnull:

```
select isnull(max(Folio), 0) from Datos;
```

Creo que eso te puede funcionar

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar, no muestra el Folio

Comment: ¿Has hecho un debug paso a paso? ¿Qué tiene la variable valor al ejecutar la segunda línea del Try? Sería bueno saber si entra por el Catch o no

Comment: Me dice :la propiedad Connection no se ha inicializado.

Comment: Pues ahí lo tienes, es justo como dice Oware, no has asignado la conexión al comando, y cuando intentas ejecutar el comando, te dice que falta por asignarle una conexión